# MapReduce Code for executing .ds2 scoring file in hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, sas, oozie, scoring

I have a .ds2 file created from SAS scoring accelerator .
The sas scoring accelerator has a macro %INDHD_RUN_MODEL which creates a MapReduce code internally to execute the .ds2 file.

How can I see the code or how can I create a similar mapreduce code.
So that I can schedule the scoring through oozie.

Answer (score 0):

The `%indhd_run_model` macro is pre-compiled and stored in `SASHOME\SASFoundation\9.4\accelmvahadp\cmacros`. It appears that the developers of this code want to keep the contents hidden.

```
libname macros 'C:\SAS\SASHome\SASFoundation\9.4\accelmvahadp\cmacros';
options sasmstore=macros mstored;

%COPY indhd_run_model / source;
```

> NOTE: The macro **%INDHD_RUN_MODEL was compiled with the /SECURE option.**  No output will be produced for this %COPY statement.
>
> ERROR: **The /SOURCE option was not specified** when the macro
>   INDHD_RUN_MODEL was compiled.

Because the `/secure` option is enabled, it is not possible to specifically view the Hadoop code template; however, you can get better insight by enabling the following options in SAS:

`options mlogic mlogicnest sastrace=',,,d' sastraceloc=saslog nostsuffix;`

This will turn on a few things:

1. The actual logic of different parts of the macro being run
2. The HiveQL queries being sent by SAS, and the response from Hadoop; output is in the SAS log

You can also play around with the arguments of the `sastrace` option to get [different types of information](https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings15/3269-2015.pdf).

Worst case, you'll need to contact SAS Tech Support to get more help on the issue. I would recommend calling, as you'll have a much faster response.

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule %INDHD_RUN_MODEL, but can't schedule the map-reduce jobs directly.SAS EP(Embeded Process) translate .ds2 code to map-reduce jobs, and then excuted it. The whole process should be a black box for end users.